# Can we make the top tool bar position fixed while scrolling?

Tags: feature-request, design, css, style

Wouldn't it be cool that this

---

[image: toolbar]

---

toolbar could be fixed for easier access for activities and votes? Saying **FIXED** i mean that while scroll it won't stay in the top of document, and will be in the top of window. Talking in css: `position: fixed`

**EDIT** for @N.N

[image: activity]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. How could the toolbar make access to activities and votes easier? Do you mean easier access to http://askubuntu.com/users/47044/gevorg-hindoyan?tab=activity?

Comment: Why i am so vague??? @BrunoPereira

Comment: @N.N. onhover of link to your account you can see you activity

Comment: That looks exactly like the tool bar, could you please be more descriptive than one sentence about what you want and why you want it.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi i want that the top bar, which is in the picture will be fixed(linke in css: `position: fixed;`) and when i will scroll down and up it will stay at same position
**WHY** because it will give easy access to your activitys...

Comment: An extension could do that easily, I like it it, would not mind having that bar fixed while I browse a post :/

Comment: Look at the toolbar at [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/). Open the page and start scrolling down. Not only does it stay at  the top, it dims once it's position 'fixes'. Pretty slick, IMHO.

Comment: @TomBrossman ya it is cooler, but our toolbar is already in the top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this userscript in the Stack Apps.

- https://stackapps.com/questions/2043/a-way-to-keep-the-user-bar-on-the-top-of-the-site-stuck-there-stickybar

It does what you are looking for. It stickies the top bar so it stays visible even if you scroll down the page.

Comment: Can't we make it part of AU's theme?